# Ошибка element is not attached to the page document

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Я пытаюсь спарсить историю игр с сайта [csgo500.io](https://csgo500.io/), но столкнулся с проблемой: количество игр в истории меняется, то `200`, то `249`, а то и `250`. Я решил взять `180` чтобы везде угодить.
Получаю доступ к элементу, парочку раз выводит, а потом ошибка: ссылка на элемент устарела. Если не вызывать `time.sleep(3)` будет выводить только один раз.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import csv

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://csgo500.io/")

time.sleep(10)

driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="login-content"]/div[3]/div/form/p[1]/label').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="login-content"]/div[3]/div/form/p[2]/label').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="login-content"]/div[3]/div/form/p[3]/label').click()

time.sleep(15)

hash_game = 0

while True:
    last_game = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="past-queue-wrapper"]/div[180]').get_attribute('class')
    h = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="past-queue-wrapper"]/div[180]/div[2]/br[1]')

    if hash_game != h:
        hash_game = h
        print(last_game)
        time.sleep(3)
```

Определение новой игры выполняю по хешу игры.

Вот тут 5 раз правильно вывело а потом ошибка:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53614/devtools/browser/81965873-c264-4a99-892c-d5687556323a

past-1  past-tooltip

past-1  past-tooltip

past-0  past-tooltip

past-0  past-tooltip

past-0  past-tooltip

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parscsgo500.py", line 21, in <module>
    last_game = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="past-queue-wrapper"]/div[180]').get_attribute('class')
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 139, in get_attribute
    attributeValue = self.parent.execute_script(
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 634, in execute_script
    return self.execute(command, {
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.102
```

Comment: Случаем не удаляются ли старые элементы? Там какой-то обновляемый список?

Comment: @gil9red, список обновляемый, вида https://prnt.sc/uf1bjl, при добавлении нового элемента он становиться самым последним то есть 250, и также когда появляется новый элемент все дивы изменяются. Но у меня идет выбор конкретного элемента, а именно 180, то есть когда в список добавляется еще одна игра, на место 180 элемента становиться другое значение. И чтобы у меня все время не выводило одну и туже игру на протяжении секунд 30, у меня идет проверка на хеш игры, и новую игру выводит только когда список еще раз измениться, то есть когда появиться в списке новая игра

Comment: Я с такими же проблемами сталкивался, когда парсил плейлист яндекс-музыки, ловите исключение: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/97063d53f0b79eee5b4132c1ecaae7b13708cc58/selenium__examples/music_yandex_ru/get_all_tracks_playlist/variant_2_with_scroll_optimization.py#L75

Comment: @gil9red, NameError: name 'StaleElementReferenceException' is not defined, ловил
try:
Код...
except StaleElementReferenceException:
    pass

Comment: сначала ловил с TimeoutException, но написало что TimeoutException не найдено, потом убрал его и уже пишет что State... не ловит

Comment: я забыл импортировать исключение, но после того я его импортировал, у меня завершается скрипт https://prnt.sc/uf247g, прописал функцию print чтобы понять из-за исключения ли это

Comment: Нужен ваш текущий код, мб вы `break` вызываете в цикле?

Comment: @gil9red, держите https://onlinegdb.com/SJE8pRvEP

Comment: try/except должен быть внутри цикла `while`

Comment: оо спасибо огромное